# how to create a wire from a portlet jsr 286 to another one jsr 168

Tags: spring, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I have been looking at online resources but no luck regarding wiring bit for jsr 286 with jsr 168. Basically I have a portlet lets say Portlet A(the source), it is using jsr 286 and portlet A needs to send an event to Porlet B(the target) which is jsr 168. I have tried creating an event publish for Portlet A and update the wsdl for Portlet B but no luck. I am using websphere and both portlet are on the same page.

I am using spring as framework.

Any idea how to do it please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good luck to you brave soul.

Comment: Unfortunately both *Public Render Parameters* and *Events* were added in JSR-286. To be honest, I don't know how people did it before :) Maybe you can experiment with session variables?

Answer (score 0):

Only portlets with `JSR 286` are allowed to send and receive Events (event handling),that's what is missing from `JSR 186`.